# Add columns to a new table row in JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have the following html:

```
<table id='myTable'>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id=col1">12</td>
      <td id=col2">55</td>
      <td id=col3">142</td>
      <td id=col4">7</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I would like to use JQuery to append everything after column 3 (col3) to a new row. Ideally I would end up with something like this:

```
<table id='myTable'>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id=col1">12</td>
      <td id=col2">55</td>
      <td id=col3">142</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id=col4">7</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Any ideas how this could be achieved? I have tried a few things but haven't been able to get it working.

Comment: Could you please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue you are facing right now.

Comment: You should provide the code about what you have tried to get the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a generic redistribution function, that takes as argument the desired number of columns, and which just fills up the rows with content from top to bottom, using that number of columns.

It could even be a jQuery plugin:

```js
$.fn.redistribute = function(maxNumCols) {
    if (maxNumCols < 1) return;
    $(this).each(function () {
        let cells = Array.from($("td", this));
        let $tr = $("tr", this);
        let rowCount = Math.ceil(cells.length / maxNumCols);
        for (let i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
            let $row = i >= $tr.length ? $("<tr>").appendTo(this) : $tr.eq(i);
            $row.append(cells.splice(0, maxNumCols));
        }
    });
}

// I/O management

function alignTable() {
    let cols = +$("input").val(); // Get desired number of columns
    $("#myTable").redistribute(cols); // Apply to table
}

// Refresh whenever input changes
$("input").on("input", alignTable);

// Refresh on page load
alignTable();
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; border: 2px solid }
td { border: 1px solid; padding: 4px }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Desired number of columns: <input type="number" size="3" value="4" min="1">

<table id='myTable'>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>55</td>
      <td>142</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>410</td>
      <td>99</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is a version with one extra statement that sets the `colspan` on the very last `td` element so it occupies the remaining columns in the last row:

```js
$.fn.redistribute = function(maxNumCols) {
    if (maxNumCols < 1) return;
    $(this).each(function () {
        let cells = Array.from($("td", this));
        let $tr = $("tr", this);
        let rowCount = Math.ceil(cells.length / maxNumCols);
        for (let i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
            let $row = i >= $tr.length ? $("<tr>").appendTo(this) : $tr.eq(i);
            $row.append(cells.splice(0, maxNumCols));
        }
        $("td", this).last().attr("colspan", rowCount * maxNumCols - cells.length + 1);
    });
}

// I/O management

function alignTable() {
    let cols = +$("input").val(); // Get desired number of columns
    $("#myTable").redistribute(cols); // Apply to table
}

// Refresh whenever input changes
$("input").on("input", alignTable);

// Refresh on page load
alignTable();
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
td { border: 1px solid; padding: 4px }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Desired number of columns: <input type="number" size="3" value="4" min="1">

<table id='myTable'>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>55</td>
      <td>142</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>410</td>
      <td>99</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I find your code really impressive, because it is very short and easy to read. Unfortunately your code outputs invalid/not semantic HTML. Each line of a table must have the same number of fields or fields with the attribute "colspan". Maybe you can extend your code that way?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where can I find documentation of that rule? I can update, but what do you want: extra cells or colspan on the last cell with a value? Note that I just followed the desired output as listed in your question...

Comment: Thanks for your extension, but I am not the author of the problem. The rule is not written in HTML directly, but HTML tables are used for "tabular data". One declaration of tabular data is "Every record shares the same set of variables" or with other words "Every row has the same set of column headers". Further the code without `colspan` does throw a warning in the [w3c markup validation service](https://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: OK, I mistook you for the author :) In that case your comment should be to the author, as they *requested* this kind of HTML in their question. It is a bit harsh to call this "invalid" HTML though. It is valid by the specs.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're still new to jQuery. To give you an idea how to solve your described problem, I have written a solution here. I hope it helps you.

```js
// parameters for splitting
var splitIndex = 3,
  splitClass = '.split-columns';

// start the splitting
splitColumnsIntoRows();

function splitColumnsIntoRows() {
  var $tables = $(splitClass),
    numberTables = $tables.length;

  if (numberTables == 0) {
    return;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < numberTables; i++) {
    iterateSplittingRows($($tables[i]).find('tr'));
  }
}

function iterateSplittingRows($currentRows) {
  var $currentRow,
    numberRows = $currentRows.length;
  
  if (numberRows == 0) {
    return;
  }
  
  for (var i = 0; i < numberRows; i++) {
    $currentRow = $($currentRows[i]);
    iterateSplittingFields($currentRow, $currentRow.find('th, td'));
  }
}

function iterateSplittingFields($currentRow, $currentFields) {
  var $newRow,
    newRows = [],
    childrenLength,
    numberFields = $currentFields.length;
  
  if (numberFields == 0) {
    return;
  }
  
  for (var i = 0; i < numberFields; i++) {
    if (i < splitIndex) {
      continue;
    }
    
    if (i % splitIndex == 0) {
      $newRow = $('<tr></tr>');
    }
    
    $newRow.append($currentFields[i]);
    
    if (i == numberFields - 1) {
      childrenLength = $newRow.children().length;
      
      // fill the row with empty fields if the length does not fit the splitIndex
      for (var j = splitIndex; j > childrenLength; j--) {
        $newRow.append($('<td></td>'));
      }
    }
    
    if (
      (i >= splitIndex && i % splitIndex == splitIndex - 1)
      ||
      i == numberFields - 1
    ){
      newRows.push($newRow);
    }
  }
  
  $currentRow.after(newRows);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable" class="split-columns">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="col_01">01</td>
      <td class="col_02">02</td>
      <td class="col_03">03</td>
      <td class="col_04">04</td>
      <td class="col_05">05</td>
      <td class="col_06">06</td>
      <td class="col_07">07</td>
      <td class="col_08">08</td>
      <td class="col_09">09</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="col_10">10</td>
      <td class="col_11">11</td>
      <td class="col_12">12</td>
      <td class="col_13">13</td>
      <td class="col_14">14</td>
      <td class="col_15">15</td>
      <td class="col_16">16</td>
      <td class="col_17">17</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="col_19">19</td>
      <td class="col_20">20</td>
      <td class="col_21">21</td>
      <td class="col_22">22</td>
      <td class="col_23">23</td>
      <td class="col_24">24</td>
      <td class="col_25">25</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```